# Copy data from merged cells on clicking

Tags: excel, vba

The below code copies cell data (range F1:H19), on clicking, and pastes them to the last row of a different worksheet of the same workbook.

When I click on merged cells nothing happens. Like when cells are empty.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("f1:h19")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
    Cancel = True
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Target.Copy Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Lastrow, 3)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Merged cells are evil. Get rid of them if you can.

Comment: When you double click a merged cell, `Target.Cells.Count` is greater than 1. I would check `Range.MergeCells` and if true proceed.

Comment: If you're copying merged cells, you might want `Target.Cells(1,1).Copy` instead of `Target.Copy`.

Comment: @BigBen could you please apply it in the code. I am beginner ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is happening, because if `Target` is a merged cell, then `Target.Cells.Count` is greater than 1.

I would change your logic using [`Range.MergeCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergecells) to determine if a merged cell was clicked:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("f1:h19")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Not Target.MergeCells Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
    Else
        If IsEmpty(Target.Cells(1, 1)) Then Exit Sub
    End If

    Cancel = True
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Target.Cells(1, 1).Copy Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Lastrow, 3)
End Sub
```